# Why is my custom theme template not found?

Tags: 7, emails, theming

In my theme's template.php file, I defined a new theme hook using [`hook_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7):

```
function MYTHEME_theme() {
  $hooks = array(
    'custombody' => array(
      'template' => 'custombody',
      'variables' => array(
        'content' => array(
          'body' => '',
        ),
      ),
      'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/templates/custom',
    ),
  );

  return $hooks;
}
```

I also placed a file named `custombody.tpl.php` under `templates/custom`.

But I can't get this template working. It's not found from Drupal. I keep getting this warning in the log:

> Theme hook custombody not found

Details:

I am trying to use this template to style the body part of HTML emails. I'm using [Swift Mailer](https://drupal.org/project/swiftmailer) to send HTML emails and I want to theme the body part with my custom theme. There is no problem on the swiftmailer part.

Normally `swiftmailer.tpl.php` prints the body text as it is:

```
<?php print $body; ?>
```

I've changed this in my own implementation of swiftmailer.tpl.php in my theme folder like that:

```
<?php print render($body); ?>
```

And I'm sending a render array as `$body`, instead of a string, what normally would be expected.

The array I'm sending is:

```
$variables['body'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'custombody',
  '#content' => array(
    'body' => 'Actual body text here',
  ),
);
```

What am I missing, that my `custombody` template is not being found?

UPDATE:

I also created a `theme_custombody()` function in my template.php file to test it, but it also doesn't work.

```
function theme_custombody($variables) {
  return 'TEST';
}
```

Comment: I hate to be the one to ask this but... have you cleared caches?

Comment: Yes, I've cleared all caches multiple times :(

Comment: The question doesn't explain in which way the theme function is used, nor in which context is invoked. Also, it doesn't show in which way the theme function replaces the one used from the module. There are some missing details that don't allow us to answer the question.

Comment: drush dis <module> -y; drush pm-uninstall <module> -y; drush en <module> -y;

Worked for me, my hook_theme array key didn't match. I changed it after the module had been enabled. No amount of cleared cache would fix it. Apparently the install process registers the theme stuff. A "drush cc theme-registry" might have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'custombody';
}
```

to add a theme hook suggestion a template called 'custombody.tpl.php'.

However it sounds like what you really want to do might be to render the `$body` directly, before it gets passed to the default template. In that case you'd use a [process or preprocess function](https://drupal.org/node/223430) to do that directly instead of doing it in the template itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had no trouble getting your code to work as-is.

I copied and pasted your theme function into my theme, created the template file at path-to-MYTHEME/templates/custom/custombody.tpl.php and cleared caches.

Then I created a test script, script.php and ran it with drush php-script script.php.

```
<?php
  echo theme('custombody', array('content' => array('body' => 'Hello, World!')));
?>
```

Some things to try:

1. Make sure that the path attribute is actually being set to what you expect. Using the PHP filter, a bootstrapped script, a drush script, or somewhere in your code,

   echo drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/templates/custom';
2. Make sure that the name of your theme is correct, no typos, both in the function name and in the path attribute.
3. Also check that the name of your theme (e.g. MYTHEME) is unique. Make sure you don't have a module using that same key for a name.
4. Make sure that your theme is enabled.